# Math.min/max.apply set values as percent of new range

Tags: javascript, math, range

I have an array list of values

```
var v=[0.009865,0.009866,0.009309,0.009831,0.009919,0.009965,0.009806,0.009509,0.009731,0.009888];
```

I calculate the min,max and difference between the two to make the range

```
var max=Math.max.apply(this,v)/100;
var min=Math.min.apply(this,v)/100;
var dif=max-min;

console.dir({'max':max,'min':min,'dif':dif});
```

the console.dir shows

```
max: 0.00009965
min: 0.00009308999999999999
dif: 0.000006560000000000005
```

Then I loop through each value attempting to convert them into percentages inside the range

**(by finding out how larger the current value is than the min, dividing the answer by the dif and multiplying the result by 100 to get the percent)**

```
for (var i=0;i<v.length;i++){
    v[i]=((v[i]-min)/dif)*100;
    console.log(v[i]);
    }
```

the console.log shows values I really don't expect to see (expected between 0-100)

```
148962.04268292672
148977.28658536574
140486.43292682915
148443.74999999985
149785.21341463405
150486.43292682915
148062.65243902427
143535.21341463405
146919.35975609746
149312.65243902427
```

What am I doing wrong?

My reference to the math: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51509/how-to-calculate-percentage-of-value-inside-arbitrary-range

Comment: can you give all in one function

Comment: That has nothing to do with my question

Comment: Why are you dividing by 100 when you set `max` and `min`? That's the problem.

Comment: Why does your loop start at `01` instead of zero?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: It's probably wrong (should be `Math`), but it's irrelevant because `min` and `max` don't care

Comment: @T.J Crowder this is Math

Comment: @Mritunjay: Just paste the 3 snippets he gave after each other in the console? There's nothing wrong with not defining a function.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It doesn't matter because `Math.max` just operates on the arguments, it doesn't care about the context.

Comment: @Barmar: I know they don't (see above), but if you're going to include something using `this`, not saying what it is is not useful. Meanwhile, I'm wondering why the OP hasn't bothered to reply to your rather cogent comment about `/100`. :-)

Comment: I changed this to Math and it makes **no difference** Math.max.apply(Math,v)/100;

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It's just a placeholder, you can put anything there. It could be `this`, or `null`, or `undefined`.

Comment: @Barmar: With `min` and `max`, yes, as I said both above and in the earlier (deleted) comment, I know that. It's a "I'm asking for help, let's make it easy for people to read my code" thing.

Comment: @Barmar +1 you are correct with why /100! Please make a simple answer so I can give you extra credit

Comment: @8DK I made an answer several minutes ago.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't divide by `100` when setting `max` and `min`:

```
var max=Math.max.apply(this,v);
var min=Math.min.apply(this,v);
```

Output:

```
84.7560975609757
84.90853658536585
0
79.57317073170726
92.9878048780489
100
75.76219512195132
30.487804878048845
64.32926829268297
88.26219512195112
```

Answer (score 0):

You could to this using `Array.map`, something like:

```
var v= [0.009865,0.009866,0.009309,0.009831,0.009919,0.009965,
        0.009806,0.009509,0.009731,0.009888]
   ,vv= v.map( function (a) { 
                return ( ( Math.abs(a-this.min) / this.diff() )*100 )
                        .toFixed(2); 
               },
               {min: Math.min.apply(null, v), 
                max: Math.max.apply(null, v),
                diff: function () { return this.max-this.min; } }
              );
 // => returns vv
 // ["84.76", "84.91", "0.00", "79.57", "92.99", "100.00", 
 //  "75.76", "30.49", "64.33", "88.26"]
```

[**MDN documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on `Array.prototype.map`